# how to turn ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386 version to the regular ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386

Tags: cd-image

I just download ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso. That was a mistake :D but i would like to find out how to make it normal (like ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386). It is possible? what packages should i install?

Thanx in advance
:D

Answer (score 2):

There is no Ubuntu alternate *distribution*. What you have downloaded is the Ubuntu alternate *installer*. The difference between the alternate installer and the standard one is in the way they work (the first is text-based, the latter is graphical), but the result is always the same.

You can read more in the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download):

> The text-based alternate installer can be downloaded from a location
>   near you. This installation CD is suited for computers unable to run
>   the graphical desktop based installation, either because their
>   computer does not meet the minimum requirements for the live cd or
>   because their computer requires configuration after the installation
>   is complete in order to use the desktop.

So the answer to your question is: you don't have do do anything because you already have the "normal" Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok maybe i said it worng, the thing about the "normality" that i was talking about is how do i get the GUI :D

Comment: Oh, so if I have understood correctly, you have installed Ubuntu using the alternate installer **and** you have chosen not to install the desktop. In this case, just install the `ubuntu-desktop` package: it depends on all the other packages you need. An another (faster) way is to re-install anything, but I suppose you already know that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The alternate CD install will get you to the same place, just select the meta package `ubuntu-desktop` during the installation.

After all is done you will reboot to the same desktop and if you had installed it with the LiveCD.

The alternate installation is not so pretty but it is not difficult at all to follow, give it a go and if you are stuck just let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between alternate and desktop CDs is the installers. The alternate has a text-based installer for the Ubuntu and therefore requires less computer resources. There is no difference once you have the system installed.

If you don't feel comfortable with text based installation I recommend that you go ahead and download the desktop version to have both Live CD and graphical user interface.